# PRAW does not fetch all comments

Tags: python, web-scraping, reddit, praw

So when I use PRAW for a thread with 77k comments I only get 466 comments. Does anybody know why that is and if it is possible to get all 77k comments?

```
user_agent = open("user_agent.txt").read()
reddit = praw.Reddit(
    client_id=open("client_id.txt").read(),
    client_secret=open("client_secret.txt").read(),
    user_agent=user_agent)

url = "https://www.reddit.com/r/soccer/comments/zp03ag/match_thread_argentina_vs_france_fifa_world_cup/"
thread = reddit.submission(url=url)

author = []
id = []
comments = []
flair = []

print(len(thread.comments))
```

Does anybody have a solution?